# Jenkins-Sonar communication on Openshift

Tags: mysql, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, openshift

I am making a development environnement based on Jenkins and Sonar.
Both are placed on isolated gears.

The Jenkins gear has been created with the Instant App option.
The Sonar gear has been created thanks to [these github indications](https://github.com/wenhao/openshift-sonar).

I created a Jenkins free-style job in order to analysis a Maven project. 
The script used on that job is based on this [wordpress article](http://deors.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/sonar-openshift/).

```
# Build script of the Job
settingsPath=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/settings.xml
settings="<settings>\n   <localRepository>$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR</localRepository>\n</settings>\n"
echo $settings > $settingsPath

# Cleaning of the workspace
mvn --global-settings $settingsPath clean test
# Preparation of Sonar informations    
export SONAR_JDBC="-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
export SONAR_DRIVER=-Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
export SONAR_DBUSER=-Dsonar.jdbc.username=xxx
export SONAR_DBPASS=-Dsonar.jdbc.password=xxx
export SONAR_URL=-Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar-alc.rhcloud.com
export SONAR_OPTS="$SONAR_JDBC $SONAR_DRIVER $SONAR_DBUSER $SONAR_DBPASS $SONAR_URL"
# Sonar analysis
mvn --global-settings $settingsPath sonar:sonar $SONAR_OPTS
```

On the execution of the mvn sonar:sonar command, I have the following error:

```
Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
```

Here is the stacktrace corresponding to this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ClientEvalcolor 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) @ ClientEvalcolor ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 3.3.1
[INFO] [03:28:09.324] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.634s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 25 03:28:10 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/182M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project ClientEvalcolor: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.): No route to host
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I know that an Openshift mysql database isn't accessible from a remote server, but Sonar seems to be runnable on Openshift, and the article that I previously linked successfully did it.

Do you have any idea about how to fix that ?

Thank you,
Alvaro C.

Comment: Are you using environment variables for setting the JDBC url?
export SONAR_JDBC="-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
The IP and PORT should likely be pulled from the gears environment variables.

Comment: We are on a case where the Jenkins job (on the jenkins gear) tries to use the Sonar mysql database (on the sonar gear). Both gears are on the same openshift account, but as they are separated, I can't use directly Sonar gear environment variables from a Jenkins script. 
But these values are correct, so the problem isn't this point. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally succeeded on making my Jenkins gear send data to my Sonar gear !

I'll explain the solution I found here, maybe it will help some people.

There a three ways to access an Openshift database:

1. The gear that contains that database can access it easily on localhost:3306. That's the usual case.
2. From your own computer, you can bind ports (with the rhc tool) in order to access the database. This can't be applied from another gear, and requires the rhc tool to keep running.
3. **Any gear from your account can access the database of a scalable application.**

Usage:

When creating the Sonar gear, it's necessary to set the gear as **scalable** (this can't be done with jenkins/diy gears). Adding a database cartridge to this gear will consume 1 gear, but this database can be accessed from any Openshift application.

Notice that this new database will have a port different than 3306 (in my case, 39536). If you don't have this, that's probably that the embedded app isn't set scalable.

The Jenkins job script that I put in my question is correct. Changing all these "xxxxx" and the port with your database info will permit Jenkins to do his job !