# Two Applications, one (MongooseJS) MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, openshift

I have a service that loads data into a MongoDB on a regular basis and another one that is a web server for CRUD operations on that database. I'm using MongooseJS to preserve my sanity with working with MongoDB.

**My question:** How do I effectively and efficiently share the schemas across these services? I would love to not have to do some copy/paste action every time a change needs to be made.

**TL;DR**

Would creating a shared module do the trick? If so, I've never done that before, how could I do that effectively? Would I have all three modules in the same repo/directory and just run one file on one process and the other in another process?

My main goal is to prevent the importing service from bringing down the web server service, which is why I'm splitting these out. I'm running on OpenShift and I'm thinking that I could have one server take care of the web server traffic and the other do the data import every 5 minutes or whatever needs to be done when.

I'd love some ideas on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to host my database on [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com/) and just deploy the full code in two places, one which runs the background job, the other which runs the web app. I haven't implemented this quite yet, but I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to make a shared database, then maybe the solution I found for [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189424/jenkins-sonar-communication-on-openshift) can help you.

In fact, if you create one of your Openshift applications as a squalable one, the embedded database will cost 1 gear but is accessible from any application of your domain. 
This may resolve your issue.