# How to feed sonar without direct database access

Tags: openshift, sonarqube

I'd like to create a build chain for open source projects I'm working on. I'm currently using  [github](https://github.com/), [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) and [coveralls](https://coveralls.io/). This is working fine but I'd like to add some kind of static code analyze.

I was thinking about hosting SonarQube on [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/), but problem is that openshift does not allow remote connection to database.

I have come to following solutions, but none of them seems to be easy to achieve:

1. Any REST API for sonar that could be used instead of raw db access
2. Any alternative for sonar that could be hosted on openshift
3. Migrate from travis to jenkins hosted on openshift and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475529/418512)
4. Any other (free) alternative to openshift which would allow raw db access
5. Any other option

1 would be an ideal solution but I've searched all sonar plugins I could find and haven't found any :/

Am I missing something? There is no easy way to host sonar without exposing db access?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least one person has gotten SonarQube running on OpenShift using the DIY cartridge:

http://majecek.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/how-to-run-sonarqube-4-0-on-openshift/

I was able to get SonarQube to start following those instructions.

EDIT: databases in OpenShift applications are only exposed publicly in scaled applications.  You will want to create your sonar app with the `-s` option if you need to populate your database from outside OpenShift.

Comment: That's true, but this will only work with Jenkins (or any other CI server) running on another openshift gear as openshift db is not accessible from outside openshift.

Comment: @airborn They are accessible, but only in a scaled application.

Comment: If application is scalable then db is accessible from other gears, not from outside ex. travis (according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189424/jenkins-sonar-communication-on-openshift)) [this](https://www.openshift.com/forums/express/external-access-to-mysql#comment-11675) post on openshift seams to confirms that. I can't find any documentation on accessing database on scaled application :/